# Odoo 10 - Add a record to an existing recordset

Tags: odoo, odoo-10

I have:

```py
myset = self.env['sale.order'].search(......)
```

And:

```py
sale_order_foo_record = self.env['sale.order'].create(....)
```

How do I add **sale_order_foo_record** to **myset**?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do:

```py
myset = self.env['sale.order'].search(...)
sale_order_foo_record = self.env['sale.order'].create(...)
myset |= sale_order_foo_record
```

Or:

```py
myset = self.env['sale.order'].search(...)
myset |= self.env['sale.order'].create(...)
```

Or:

```py
myset = self.env['sale.order'].search(...) + self.env['sale.order'].create(...)
```